# Incorrect render image

Tags: rendering

[image]

Hey there! Can you solve this problem? Scene is looking OK in rendered viewport, but something messed in final render. I am using volumetric matherial only in the ocean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking in the outliner to see if something that is hidden(the eye is grayed out) is set to render(the camera icon is NOT grayed out).  If you want to hide this object you can click the camera and it will not render in the final render.

Comment: The problem was in the hidden cube, which i've used in the boolean oprations and hadn't diasable for rendering. Thank you.